# Unable to set breakpoint in async in chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-chrome-devtools, firebase-authentication

I'm using the Este react native starter kit. After I changed the code to point to my firebase account, the application crashes on the line  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions in the following code. I'm unable to set debug breakpoint inside this return () block. Breakpoint works other places, I think this is either bcoz of async or the fact that code block is inside return. How can I debug this now?

```
        export function nativeSignIn(providerName) {
      return ({ FBSDK: { AccessToken, LoginManager }, firebaseAuth }) => {

          invariant(providerName === 'facebook',
           `${providerName} provider is not yet supported in nativeSignIn.`);

          const getPromise = async () => {

            debugger;
            alert(`LoginManager=${LoginManager}, sting=${JSON.stringify(LoginManager)}`)
            const result = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(facebookPermissions);
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

          return {
            type: 'FIREBASE_SIGN_IN',
            payload: getPromise(),
          };
      };
    }
```

Comment: it seems like getPromise is calling itself in return statement. Above code won't work because getPromise won't get called. is this your actual code or there is formatting error here?

Comment: When I simply moved the entire function to the bottom, it worked. Weird. May be some issue with chrome developer tools